# Table creation, how to align one column left and having two rows to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a column aligned left and then two rows to the right of it in a table like in my picture. Red and blue boxes are both supposed to be 50% of the height and 60% of the width. (sorry about the crude photo, Photoshop bugged out on me and paint isn't my forte)
I've tried to create the table but can only seem to get it in rows.

Also in one of the boxes I have text that I want to be on the bottom of the table. I've tried to achieve this using `vertical-align:bottom;` but I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve this.

I understand this is a simple question but can't wrap my head about it. 
Here is my fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/DPMC87/fmx9o2a2/[image]

Comment: @Rachel-Gallen any idea?

Comment: Do you want to use table only layout?

Comment: @Manoj-Kumar If there's an easier better way definitely not. It's just the only way I could think of doing it and keeping text inside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for tables or even flexbox for this layout! You can accomplish it using a few floats, and it still remains fully responsive.

Here is a screenshot of the final result:

[image: Layout]

And **here is a live demo of the code that produces that result:**

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body, #outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#blk {
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}
#red, #blu {
    height: 50%;
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
}

#blk {
    background: black;
}

#red {
    background: red;
}

#blu {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
#blu > span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="blk"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="blu"><span>Text aligned bottom</span></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/229zjpj7/

Answer (score 1):

No need for floats to do this!

You can do this [with flexbox](http://jsfiddle.net/martco/3e58pt3q/2/).

There are a few benefits to going with flexbox over floats:

1. Much less CSS
2. No clearfix hacks
3. Flexbox more appropriately fits your use case

[image]

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 500px;
}

.left {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: black;
}

.right {
    flex: 1.5;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.right__red {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: red;
}

.right__blue {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    
    <div class="right">
        <div class="right__red"></div>
        <div class="right__blue"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The key is setting the `.right` div to having 1.5 times the width of the `.left` div. This will give it 60% of the width.

Use `flex-direction: column` to allow the red and blue cells to take up 50% of the height of the container, no matter how tall it is.

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a great source of info on flexbox. In some ways I think that flexbox is a step above floats, which were a step above table-based layout.

Answer (score 0):

Table layout is also a good way to accomplish what you want. 
but i would prefer using float property.

Yes we have used fixed height for blocks now , in my code it is 200px, and using fixed height for it is not a good option. 
i would write small JS, for it to calculate height itself. or may be same height js for both columns.

HTML

```
<div class="column-wrap">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box align">
            <div class="holder">
                I am verticall bottom aligned
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.column-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    height: 200px;
}
.column:first-child {
    width: 40%;
    background :red;
    height: 200px;
}
.box {
    height: 50%;
    background : blue;
}
.box:first-child {
    background : black;
}
.align {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.align:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    marin-right: -0.25em; /* margin because inline block element takes 4px space for it. */
}
.align .holder {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

here is a link to fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/fmx9o2a2/6/

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is in the table.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 16px/1.4'Source Code Pro';
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
}
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.main {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.black {
  background: black;
  width: 40%;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
}
td {
  color: white;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table class="main">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="black" rowspan='2'>
        <h3><u>It's Very Responsive</u></h3>
        <p>This is the 1st column. To extend this cell, use the rowspan attribute.</p>
        width: 40% height: 100%
      </td>
      <td class="blue">
        <h3><u>It's Designed Tight, No Misalignments</u></h3>
        <p>This is the second column and the first row.</p>
        width: 60% height: 50%
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="red">
        <h3><u>There are Essential Properties in .Main</u></h3>
        <p>This is the second column and the second row.</p>
        width: 60% height: 50%
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Whoa great stuff guys! Thanks for all the answers. All very good options but I liked @Maximillian-Laumeister and zer00ne answer the best as they made more sense to me. The flexbox stuff looks interesting and I'll have a look into it. Really appreciate all the effort in the answers. Great stuff guys!